# How to activate a setter method without input in the main program code?

Tags: c#, class, getter-setter, setter

I'm working on a program that needs to check if a *value* is an *integer* before applying it to an *attribute* of a *class*. This **must** be done in a *setter ("set") method*.

```
internal class Dummy {
    private int number;
            
    public int Number {
        get { return number; }
        set { Console.Write("Input number: "); if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value) == true) { number = value; Console.WriteLine("The number is " + number + "."); } else { Console.WriteLine("That is not a number."); } }
    }
}
```

I tried to make the input in the main program a string (objectName.Number = Console.ReadLine();) instead of an int (objectName.Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()):), but this obviously gave me an **error**.

I've then tried to just make the input an int, but use a string input when running the program. This would lead to a **crash**.

The only way I could make this work was for the user to enter a *"useless" number* (for the first *"main program" input* to be discarded) and then input the right one when prompted with *"Input number: "*; but this *"solution"* looks and feels clunky.

I'm open to different ways of doing this, but remember, the setter **absolutely must** be the code that checks whether the value is an int (and then apply it accordingly).

Comment: If the setter must contain that check the property can't be a an int itself but must be something common like object. Reading from Console in the setter to get the value in the first place is a nogo by the way.

Comment: The get/set isn't the place to be reading the number from Console. That should be done within the main program. Also, it is better to do validation is a method in the main class of the program, then call a save method to do the actual save.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you can't put all the read and writes out to the Console into a Property like that. A Property get/set can have some logic in it, but you're attempting to use the Property "Number" as a function.

Here is a sample of some working code that will do what you need.

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        int _number;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           new Program().Run(); 
        
        }

        // This is a "Property"
        public int Number
        {
            get {return _number;}
            set {_number = value;}
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
            
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            int i;

            if (Int32.TryParse(input, out i))
            {
                Number = i;

                Console.WriteLine("Input was {0}", Number);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input \"{0}\" was not a number!", input);
            }

        }

    }

}

`
```